# ExtJS: grids data linking

Tags: extjs, grid, store, edit

I have a two Ext.panel.Grid (let's call it "A" and "B")
When i select line in the grid "A", the data loads to the grid "B. The main problem is the grid "B" is editable, and when i select another record in "A", the changes in "B" record are lost :(

there are next logic in controller

```
"grid id[A]": {
    selectionchange: function(grid, record) {
        this.getGridB.getStore().loadData( record.get('options'), false );
    }
}
```

and the sample record is:

```
{
    name: "Item1",
    owner: "user1",
    options: [
        {
            value: "345",
            name: "option1"
        },
        {
            value: "100500",
            name: "option2"
        }
    ]
}
```

where i should store the changed values? Or is there another, more "straight" solution?

Comment: Is it an 1:n relationship?

Comment: yes, there is an 1:n relation

Comment: Then it is easier to use associations. Please mind that association syntax has changed between Ext 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

> LoadData() loads an array of data straight into the Store.If the data is in the correct format with respect to the model of other store then we can use this method directly loading the model object. If you wish to add data to the existing records in the store,you have to set append to true which is by default false.

```
store.loadData(data, true);
```

> where **data :  Ext.data.Model[]/Object[]**
>
> So it should be something like this :

```
 listeners: {
     selectionchange: function(thisObj, selected, eOpts) {
         gridB = Ext.getCmp('gridA');
         gridB.getStore().loadData(selected, true);//true to append records
         gridB.getView().refresh();
     }
 },
```